# Read PDF content in Android using Apache PDFBox

Tags: android, kotlin, pdfbox

I am trying to read the pdf content text page by page, but I never used PDFBox before, I wrote the following code just using Autocomplete and Google. Now I want to get the page content. This is an Android application.

```
PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(applicationContext)

thread {
    val ins = resources.openRawResource(
        resources.getIdentifier("file",
            "raw", packageName))
    debug(TAG, "Loading PDF...")
    val document = PDDocument.load(ins)
    debug(TAG, "PDF Loaded.")

    for (i in 0 until document.numberOfPages) {
        val page = document.getPage(i)
        debug(TAG, page.hasContents())
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is one sample app available, Might be useful for you. https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/tom_roush/pdfbox/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: this code sample contains only to create a pdf file, not to read a pdf file. Do you have any other example snippet that shows how to read a pdf file?

Comment: This sample contain below functions
(1)createPdf
(2)renderFile
(3)fillPFDForm
(4)stripTextInPDF
(5)createEncryptedPdf

Please go through entire example there are different methods for that.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking like someone will give me a code snippet, so I can just copy-paste. that was so stupid. Even though that code snippet doesn't have a straight answer it clearly explains how to use the PDFBox, thanks. I found the answer, I will post it now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no need an explanation for this because you can clearly understand it from this code snippet.

```
PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(applicationContext)

thread {
    val ins = resources.openRawResource(
        resources.getIdentifier("file",
            "raw", packageName))
    debug(TAG, "Loading PDF...")
    val document = PDDocument.load(ins)
    debug(TAG, "PDF Loaded.")

    val reader = PDFTextStripper()

    for (i in 0 until document.numberOfPages) {
        reader.startPage = i
        reader.endPage = i
        val content = reader.getText(document)

        debug(TAG, content)
    }
}
```